# cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes errors on trials to update a custom attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id <pool id> --username admin --user-attributes Name="custom:Organization",Value="myOrg"
```

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-update-user-attributes.html) the above command should update a custom attribute I defined for my user pool. 
So I defined the custom attribute **after** the initial creation of the pool and creation of a few users for testingpurposes. I also enabled read/write permissions for the application on this attribute but when running the above command all I get is:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the AdminUpdateUserAttributes operation: Invalid user attributes: custom:Organization: Attribute cannot be updated.
```

I guess i am missing some micro configuration somewhere but I could find what it is...

Answer (score 5):

Check the mutable settings for the custom attribute. You can find the attributes settings under the "Attributes" tab of the user pool.

Comment: It's correct, I was having the same problem, but it was due custom attribute mutable option was set to false, I recreated the pool with mutable = true, and it works.